# Is there a jenkins job-dsl block/code for defining Gradle-Artifactory plugin configuration?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, jenkins-job-dsl

In jenkins job, I use the gradle-artifactory plugin to publish the artifact to specific path (which is mentioned in build.gradle of the git project) in Artifactory.
I wanted to have my Jenkins jobs through job-dsl. What would be the job-dsl code/block for gradle-artifactory plugin configuration?
I tried to use `ArtifactoryGradleConfigurator` class but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifactory plugin is not yet supportet by job dsl. What you need to do is create the according XML config by yourself via the [configure block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block). Here is an example for you where you can start:

```groovy
job('artifactory-config') {
  configure {
    it / buildWrappers / 'org.jfrog.hudson.gradle.ArtifactoryGradleConfigurator' {
      deployMaven 'false'
      deployIvy 'false'
      deployBuildInfo 'true'
      includeEnvVars 'false'
      deployerCredentialsConfig {
        credentialsId 'foobar'
        overridingCredentials 'false'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The actual configuration you need to do is a bit more extensive. Just have a look at the *config.xml* of your job, there you will find the XML tag for `ArtifactoryGradleConfigurator`. It will look like this:

```xml
<project>
  <buildWrappers>
    <org.jfrog.hudson.gradle.ArtifactoryGradleConfigurator">
      <deployMaven>false</deployMaven>
      <deployIvy>false</deployIvy>
      <deployBuildInfo>true</deployBuildInfo>
      <includeEnvVars>false</includeEnvVars>
      <deployerCredentialsConfig>
        <credentials>
          <username></username>
          <password></password>
        </credentials>
        <credentialsId></credentialsId>
        <overridingCredentials>false</overridingCredentials>
      </deployerCredentialsConfig>
      <resolverCredentialsConfig>
        <credentials>
          <username></username>
          <password></password>
        </credentials>
        <credentialsId></credentialsId>
        <overridingCredentials>false</overridingCredentials>
      </resolverCredentialsConfig>
    </org.jfrog.hudson.gradle.ArtifactoryGradleConfigurator>
  </buildWrappers>
</project>
```

One important thing for you to know is, you do not need to configure the whole block. But when you miss any important XML tag, the job will be generated, but you will not see the configuration in the UI. Just try to get the XML to be generated 1:1. The [Jenkins Job DSL Playground](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) is a nice tool to help you do that.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out what I missed, as I am doing this on new jenkins box. I forget to install gradle plugin. I know, thats dumb! Once I installed it, it is good in recognizing artifactory name & URL. But it was unable to recognize repository names until I click on refresh button. Then this thing helped. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26997.

Answer (score 0):

Nice thing about the Jenkins Artifactory plugin for Gradle is that all it does is applying [Gradle Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) (which is, of course, all code – Gradle DSL). So instead of applying the plugin from Jenkins UI you can apply it directly in Gradle, in code.